# Tabular individual vertical alignment in header row with varwidth columns

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, varwidth

How can i bottom align the header row only? Is there a way to do it with \rowstyle or something similar as i did to make the whole row \bf?

I would prefer not to use multiple tabulars.

```
(\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
#1\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \caption{\newline Weight regulation: long-term clinical trials}
        \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
        \ra{1.3}
        \newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}[t]{3cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}    
        \begin{tabular}{@{}$M^M^M@{}}\toprule
            \rowstyle{\bf\raggedbottom}
            First Author \newline Year \newline Country & Bottom &  Bottom \tabularnewline
            \midrule
            \rowstyle{\raggedright}
            This needs to be on top as it is& Also this one& And this
            \tabularnewline
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{flushleft} Text in bottom of table.
        \end{flushleft}
        \label{table1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
The text doesn't wrap with the proposed solutions below, but that is not the most important thing in the header row, since \\ or \cr can be used to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `This needs to be on top as it is` means what? On top of what?

Comment: It just needs to be aligned at top as it is already, no need to change that.

The only thing i need changed is the vertical alignement in the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution that doesn't  require  `\rowstyle` for the first row. The `makecell` package allows for line breaks in cells, and a common formatting with the  `\thead, \makecell` and a few other commands.

Further, your caption and text at the bottom of the table will use a whole `\linewidth`, which is probably not what you want. It couldn't be detected because they were not long enough. I suggest using the `threeparttable` package, which limits theit width to the real table width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off, labelsep=newline, skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{makecell,}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lb}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
#1\ignorespaces
}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\varwidth[t]{3cm}}l<{\endvarwidth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Weight regulation: long-term clinical trials. Some more text}
    \ra{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}$M^M^M@{}}
      \toprule
      %\rowstyle{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedbottom}
      \thead{First Author \\ Year \\ Country} &\thead{Bottom} & \thead{Bottom} \tabularnewline
      \midrule
      \rowstyle{\raggedright}
      This needs to be on top as it is & Also this one & And this \tabularnewline
      \addlinespace
      \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes} \item[\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}] Text in bottom of table. Text in bottom of table. Text in bottom of table. Text in bottom of table.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \label{table1}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution with the makecell package, it simplifies a lot! And also thanks for suggesting \threeparttable, but my table will exceed the width of the caption when completed.

Comment: Will it also exceed the text at the bottom of the table?

Comment: Great point! But yes, i will need all the space i can get for this one :)
But it is very useful indeed, and it will undoubtedly come in handy in the future.

Comment: I worked a little more on my table and i ran in to an issue with this solution. The space-suppressing qualities of @{} gets disrupted by makecell. is there a way that this quality could be restored with adding something in the preample perhaps? See my edited 1st post for clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well. Do you mean that `Bottom` should be right-aligned?

Comment: Yes that was what my brain wanted, but that is nonsense since the only thing @{} does, is remove the edge from the longest cell in the last column. Sorry for asking - I need to sleep.

Comment: If you want the last head to be right-aligned (in the preamble I defined the alignment a `lb`, the default is `cc`), you can use the optional argument of \thead:  `\thead[rb]{Bottom}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (version ≥ 6.3 of 2021-10-18). The columns `V` are the `V`-columns defined by `varwidth` (and supported by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,varwidth}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off, labelsep=newline, skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Weight regulation: long-term clinical trials.}
\begin{NiceTabular}
  [tabularnote = Text in bottom of table. Text in bottom of table. 
                 Text in bottom of table. Text in bottom of table.] 
  {@{}p[l]{3cm}V{3cm}V{3cm}@{}}
\toprule
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block[b]{}{First Author\\ Year\\ Country}
& Bottom & Bottom \\
\midrule
This needs to be on top as it is & Also this one & And this \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

One can just put the desired elements into a `\Longstack`, though I had to add an extra group, perhaps because of its inclusion in a `varwidth` environment.  To summarize, I added this to the preamble

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
```

to get left-aligned stacks, with `\cr` as the row separator.  Then, in the `tabular`, I used this for the entry:

```
{\Longstack{First Author\cr Year\cr Country}}
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
#1\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \caption{\newline Weight regulation: long-term clinical trials}
        \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
        \ra{1.3}
        \newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}[t]{3cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}    
        \begin{tabular}{@{}$M^M^M@{}}\toprule
            \rowstyle{\bf\raggedbottom}
{\Longstack{First Author\cr Year\cr Country}}& Bottom &  Bottom \tabularnewline
            \midrule
            \rowstyle{\raggedright}
            This needs to be on top as it is& Also this one& And this
            \tabularnewline
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{flushleft} Text in bottom of table.
        \end{flushleft}
        \label{table1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the stackengine! it is a very simple solution to my problem.
But i don't know what you mean by "i had to add an extra group"? In the preample?

Comment: @Nowak What I mean is I had to place the `\Longstack{...}` inside an extra set of braces, as in `{\Longstack{...}}`. The braces serve as group delimiters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.

Another thing, i worked a little more on my table and i ran into an issue with the space-suppressing qualities of @{}. It gets disrupted by the stackengine somehow. is there a way this quality could be restored with adding something in the preample perhaps? See my edited 1st post for clarification.

Comment: @Nowak I compiled your edit code and am not sure what the issue is. The table looked good, even with the `@{}` code present.

Comment: I realized that there is no issue. For some reason i wanted the last column in the header row to be right-aligned, but that makes no sense. Sorry for asking, i will remove the issue from my 1st post.